# null value in column "job_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to upload a pdf file but I keep getting an integrity error, when I try to submit the pdf file, it looks like I have some blank space in the DB which I don't know, may someone please help me! The error is:

```
IntegrityError at /posts/resume/
null value in column "job_id" violates not-null constraint
```

models.py

```
class Jobs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    jobs_type = models.CharField(max_length=80, choices=JOB_CHOICES)
    description = models.TextField()
    requirements = models.TextField()
    posted_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    deadline = models.DateField()
    link = models.URLField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    contacts = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-posted_date',)



class Application(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="application",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    job = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    professional_summary = models.TextField()
    resume = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

form.py

```
 class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
        resume = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'onchange': 'uploadPreview(this)'}))
        oss_resume = forms.CharField (widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ('professional_summary', 'resume', )
```

views.py

```
class CreateApplicationView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ApplicationForm
    model = Application
    message = _("Your Event has been created.")
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:list_jobs')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.object=None
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def form_valid(self, form):
            resume = form.cleaned_data['oss_resume']

            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            submit = form.save()
            submit.user= self.request.user

            if not resume:
                return ('posts/no_resume.html')

            else:
                submit.save()
        def get_success_url(self):
            messages.success(self.request, self.message)
            return reverse('posts:list_events')

        def get_object(self):
            resume = kwargs.get('resume')
            return Application.objects.get(resume=resume)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^list-jobs/$', JobsListView.as_view(), name='list_jobs'),





url(r'^resume/$', CreateApplicationView.as_view(), name='resume'),
```

the results is

```
IntegrityError at /posts/resume/
null value in column "job_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (7, first job , processing.pdf, 2019-07-10 11:40:06.873356+00, null, null).
```

Comment: Could you post the model in which you have the job_id field?

Comment: i think  it in the Jbs model

Comment: i mean Jobs  model, its just above there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Application` model has a `ForeignKey` to `Jobs` model (which I think should be just `Job`, but that's another matter), but it is not nullable/blank. It seems to me your view does not provide a `Jobs` instance to the `Application` instance that's being created with the PDF upload, hence the error.

**Update:**

One way of doing this would be to add `null=True, blank=True` to your `job` field declaration on the `Application` model. However, this doesn't sound like a good solution, as an application should be associated to a job. So you need to allow the user to pick the job that he's applying to in the `Application` form or automatically assign that job to the application when you process the form submission in the `CreateApplicationView`.

**Update 2:**

In your `ApplicationForm`, try to do this:

```py
 class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
        resume = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'onchange': 'uploadPreview(this)'}))
        oss_resume = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
        job = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Jobs.objects.all())


    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ('professional_summary', 'resume', 'job')
```

I've added the field in the form for the person to pick the Job he/she's applying for. This should fix the error or push you in the right direction.

Comment: may you please tell me how to do that, sorry i'm a curious newbie

Comment: @miharbi98 I've added a couple of alternatives to my answer, check if it makes sense to you.

Comment: Did it help, @miharbi98?

Comment: sorry for late response  but i'm still struggling with it

Comment: @miharbi98 I've updated my answer once again, please take a look.